# Create text file in multiple directories - Python

Tags: python, windows

How would I create `foo.txt` in multiple directories using python? For example, let's say I have this tree

```
example
   --- folder1
   --- folder2
   --- folder3
```

How would I put foo.txt in each folder? I've tried this code but it didn't work.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        f = open(name + '/file.txt', 'w')
        f.write('ex')
```

Comment: Not a python professional, but I think you have to close the file you opened first, before you can reopen something new. The with statement is handy here as it handles it for you.

Comment: Nope. Still didn't work. `f.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `join` path parts together, including the `root` part (here `/`)

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        with open(os.path.join(root,name,'file.txt'), 'w') as f:
            f.write('ex')
```

Aside:

1. if you don't run this code as `root` you'll get an exception on protected directories and it will stop. Maybe consider starting a little lower than `/` (for instance your home directory) or catch the write exceptions to be able to continue.
2. this code is "dangerous" because it will create a file in *all* directories (you have to run it as root to do so)
3. use a `with` block so the file is automatically closed when exiting from the block

Comment: Didn't work. My folders have spaces in. Does that change anything?

Comment: nope. Didn't work how? did you get an exception? nothing?

Comment: It ran the file and I saw nothing onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that writes to a given path and then loop through it. e.g. something like:

```
def write_txt_file(dir, filename, text):
    d = dir + filename + ".txt"
    outF = open(d, "w")
    outF.write(text)
    outF.close()

dirs = ["P:/example/folder1/", "P:/example/folder2/", "P:/example/folder3/"]

for dir in dirs:
    write_txt_file(dir, "foo", "Hi there!")
```